# Does ship shape affect Hyperdrive class?

Tags: star-wars, spaceship, hyperspace

Most fast ships in the *Star Wars* universe have very aerodynamic shapes.

There seems to be a direct correlation between how sleek a ship looks, and its Hyperdrive class.

Some [examples](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hyperdrive):

- First Death Star: Class 4 Hyperdrive
- Nubian: Class 1.8 Hyperdrive
- *Millennium Falcon*: Class 0.5 Hyperdrive

Is there an in-canon link between ship shape and its Hyperdrive class?

Anything from the Extended Universe (pre- and post-Disney) is acceptable.

Comment: Han's new ship is a flying brick and it's got a reasonably decent hyperdrive

Comment: Your examples would suggest not. The Death Star and *Millennium Falcon* are not sleek but the sleek Nubian ship is in the middle of them by class. Hyperdrive class is a property of the hyperdrive, not the ship.

Comment: What sorts of sources would you be interested in seeing answers from? I ask because the main works I'm aware of that go into detail on hyperdrive speeds are RPG sourcebooks and the like. (Players want to know how fast their ship goes - everyone else just travels at the speed of the plot.)

Comment: I'm okay with anything in the Extended Universe, including the now-disavowed pre-Disney canon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ship *shape* does not affect its hyperdrive class at all, no. Hyperdrive class only describes how *fast* the ship can go through hyperspace, with a lower rating equating to faster speeds. Its size, however, does limit whether or not it can have a hyperdrive and how fast it can go based on hyperdrive size and power requirements.

For example, the Jedi starfighters used during the Clone Wars era, specifically the Delta-7/7B and the Eta-2 starfighters in *Attack of the Clones* and *Revenge of the Sith* respectively, were far too small to be equipped with a hyperdrive. The Eta-2's cockpit is barely large enough to accommodate its pilot and its ion sublight drive is likewise quite compact. In both of these small starfighters, an external hyperdrive booster, or ring, had to be used.

An X-wing or Y-wing, on the other hand, has a hyperdrive installed. These are both quite larger than either of the two Jedi starfighters and since they have higher power outputs and larger fuel resources, their spaceframes can accommodate a hyperdrive easily.

A midway point in terms of starfighter development, the Z-95 Headhunter, *could* be retrofitted with a hyperdrive, but it also ran into another problem that hyperdrive-capable ships had: Navigational systems. The Z-95 could only store a single pre-computed set of destination coordinates (plus their hyperdrive vector) in its navigation system and, as these coordinates require specific and intense mathematical calculations, it would be nearly impossible for a pilot to calculate a new set themselves. The X-wing and Y-wing, by dint of having an onboard astromech droid that specialized in calculating and storing multiple sets of hyperspace coordinates, did not have this issue. Ditto for larger ships with better onboard navigation computers.

Now, when it comes to larger ships like the *Millennium Falcon*, hyperdrive size is much less of an issue. The *Falcon* itself boasted an exceptionally fast hyperdrive, because it had been fitted by Lando Calrissian who used a hyperdrive engine that was twice the size of the stock drive fitted to the YT-1300 series freighters yet gave vastly improved speed. But the *Falcon* is a relatively small ship and hardly stock configuration; other vessels of comparable size fitted with hyperdrives might be faster or slower depending solely on the unit installed.

The Death Star, on the other hand, had what was a fairly slow hyperdrive in part as a result of its sheer size. According to the Legends continuity, the Death Star actually used 123 individual hyperdrive units slaved together to transport the station through hyperspace. It's possible there was some inherent risk of making the Death Star go any faster through hyperspace, or that even with its massive power generation reactor, such speeds wouldn't be attainable due to however physics works (or doesn't work) in *Star Wars* hyperspace, so the bank of Class Four hyperdrives was the best the Empire could do at the time for a vessel so immense.

Answer (score 1):

#### Your Examples Do Not Align With Your Thesis

The "sleekest" ship in your list, the Nubian vessel has the middle ranked hyperdrive system.

#### That said... Good, Fast, Cheap - pick any two.

As far as we know, Hyperdrive Class is purely a measure of speed. While it's certainly related to the underlying hardware of the hyperdrive, there are likely other factors involved - mass and volume of the vessel, fuel efficiency, reactor output, quality and durability, expense, etc.

For example, very small, high performance fighters - like the [Delta-7 *Aethersprite*-class](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Delta-7_Aethersprite-class_light_interceptor) and the [Eta-2 *Actis*-class](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Eta-2_Actis-class_light_interceptor) used by the Jedi Order - likely did not have the mass or volume to dedicate to a hyperdrive. They used external hyperdrive rings instead. Cheap starfighters, like most TIEs, lack hyperdrives because well... they're cheap.

Something like the [Death Star](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/DS-1_Orbital_Battle_Station) is going to need either a single massive hyperdrive, or a large number of smaller units - [legends says the latter](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/DS-1_Orbital_Battle_Station/Legends). It is unlikely that the individual [SSP06 hyperdrive generators](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/SSP06_hyperdrive_generator) would be "Class 4" when installed in another ship, but rather as configured in the Death Star, they have "a hyperdrive system that meets the criteria of Class Four".

The precise criteria of each class of hyperdrive is an entirely different question.